# Laravel can't login using attempt

Tags: php, laravel-5.3

As my title mentioned, I am trying to login using `auth()->attempt($credentials, false)` but it always return `false`.

After further digging into the problem, I finally found that it was due to this:

```
public function validateCredentials(UserContract $user, array $credentials)
    {
        $plain = $credentials['password'];

        return $this->hasher->check($plain, $user->getAuthPassword());
    }
```

The `$user->getAuthPassword()` returns `null` even though the `$user` have password on the original while I dump it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually this is very basic mistake. As I had mixed with some other programming language style of code (getter and setter).

I set a `password` variable on the **User::class**.
By such, when it retrieving `$user->getAuthPassword()` it will take the variable data instead of attribute data.

I'm sharing this knowledge in case someone else encounters the same issue. As I tried to solve this problem for about 2 days and wasn't able to find anything.